# Изменять класс блока при hover вложенного в него элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.
задача нескольких абстрактная и не связана с конкретной версткой, потому без указания html опишу задачу
в Dom есть множество элементом, представим, что в блоке есть ссылка. надо добавлять/удалять класс у блока при наведении курсора на ссылку. при этом блок или любой другой элемент может быть в разной удаленности в структуре, главное, что элемент ща пределами ссылки и поэтому нужен js/jquery , чистый CSS тут не поможет.
ценлять все следует на классы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

допустим что верстка выглядит так

```
<div class="hover">
    <div><a class='linkToHover'>Ссылка</a></div>
</div>
```

внутри которого ссылка, тогда код будет выглядеть так

```
$('a.linkToHover').hover(function(){
    $(this).parents('.hover').addClass('hoverClass');
},function(){
    $(this).parents('.hover').removeClass('hoverClass');
})
```

если не является родителем то тогда  по классу напрямую

```
$('a.linkToHover').hover(function(){
    $('.hover').addClass('hoverClass');
},function(){
    $('.hover').removeClass('hoverClass');
})
```

Comment: а если скажем блок будет не родителем, а просто "соседним" по отношению к ссылке?

Comment: тогда напрямую по классу